# how to get picklist in lightening flow based on specific record types of SObject - salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

**My requirement** -

1. I have Case object and it contains Type as one filed ( it's data type is Picklist).
2. I have 2 record types on case object ( a. InternalCase b. ExternalCase ) where these 2 record types have different picklist values .
3. In Lightening flows i am trying to create resource where resource type is picklist and on Case object

- here where i am getting all picklist values of case irrespective of Record Type
- But i want picklist of specific Record Type  values only  in lightening flows .

is  it possible in lightening flow ?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by a custom implementation.

We can implement a custom LWC component that takes object name, field name, and record type as parameters and generates a dynamic picklist based on the inputs.

On selecting the picklist value, you can assign the same value to a flow variable.

Comment: Hello Jasneet Dua

Comment: could you post that Lwc Componet  code reference here and do u mean write apex method to get dynamic picklist values right ?

Comment: @MaldannaGk correct, you can refer to the following links:

https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/12/15/dynamic-picklist-value-in-lightning-web-components/

and 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation

Comment: is it possible in apex code to get picklist values of specific record type

Comment: u can leverage lwc getPicklistValues method from uiObjectInfoApi module to do that. 
For more info:
https://www.swdcworld.com/2020/09/get-picklist-values-in-lightning-web.html